# how to generate oauth_timestamp,oauth_nonce ,oauth_signature for react native

Tags: react-native

I am working on react native app. I want to connect my app to woocommerce api, for that I need to pass consumer key,time stamp, auth signature while making network requests. So My url should be as shown below:

```
http://quflip.com/wp-json/wc/v1/products?oauth_consumer_key=ck_75a6b3f5cf97e03a2bd42c8e4dffaefe07538bfb&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1480656796&oauth_nonce=2qL1ca&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=6AJyrlsjcm2BxlMS1HSo3b0TTek=
```

So , how can acheive the url request as shown above
?

Comment: What is exactly the problem? Can't you just concatenate the query parameters to the requests?

Comment: I tried that, but it is not working

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get  an error when you issue the request, is the URL not built correctly...?